# How to obtain the WYSIWYG body of an email message using MimeKit

Tags: c#, email, mailkit, mimekit

I was using a library called EAgetmail to retrieve the body of a specified email and it was working well, however I am now using Mailkit. The problem is with EAgetmail the equivalent of message.body returns the body as the user sees it in email clients, but in mailkit it returns a lot of different data.

This is the relevant code:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.Connect(emailServer, 993, true);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate(username, password);
    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
    SearchQuery query;
    if (checkBox.IsChecked == false)
    {
        query = SearchQuery.DeliveredBefore((DateTime)dateEnd).And(
            SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter((DateTime)dateStart)).And(
            SearchQuery.SubjectContains("Subject to find"));
    }
    else
    {
        query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains("Subject to find");
    }
    foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query))
    {
        var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
        formEmails.Add(message.TextBody);
        messageDate.Add(message.Date.LocalDateTime);
    }
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I also tried message.Body.ToString() and searching through the message parts for plain text, but neither worked.
My question is how do I replicate the effect of EAgetmail's .body property using Mailkit (to return only the body contents in plain text, as the user sees)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A common misunderstanding about email is that there is a well-defined message body and then a list of attachments. This is not really the case. The reality is that MIME is a tree structure of content, much like a file system.

Luckily, MIME does define a set of general rules for how mail clients should interpret this tree structure of MIME parts. The `Content-Disposition` header is meant to provide hints to the receiving client as to which parts are meant to be displayed as part of the message body and which are meant to be interpreted as attachments.

The `Content-Disposition` header will generally have one of two values: `inline` or `attachment`.

The meaning of these values should be fairly obvious. If the value is `attachment`, then the content of said MIME part is meant to be presented as a file attachment separate from the core message. However, if the value is `inline`, then the content of that MIME part is meant to be displayed inline within the mail client's rendering of the core message body. If the `Content-Disposition` header does not exist, then it should be treated as if the value were `inline`.

Technically, every part that lacks a `Content-Disposition` header or that is marked as `inline`, then, is part of the core message body.

There's a bit more to it than that, though.

Modern MIME messages will often contain a `multipart/alternative` MIME container which will generally contain a `text/plain` and `text/html` version of the text that the sender wrote. The `text/html` version is typically formatted much closer to what the sender saw in his or her WYSIWYG editor than the `text/plain` version.

The reason for sending the message text in both formats is that not all mail clients are capable of displaying HTML.

The receiving client should only display one of the alternative views contained within the `multipart/alternative` container. Since alternative views are listed in order of least faithful to most faithful with what the sender saw in his or her WYSIWYG editor, the receiving client should walk over the list of alternative views starting at the end and working backwards until it finds a part that it is capable of displaying.

Example:

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  text/html
```

As seen in the example above, the `text/html` part is listed last because it is the most faithful to what the sender saw in his or her WYSIWYG editor when writing the message.

To make matters even more complicated, sometimes modern mail clients will use a `multipart/related` MIME container instead of a simple `text/html` part in order to embed images and other multimedia content within the HTML.

Example:

```
multipart/alternative
  text/plain
  multipart/related
    text/html
    image/jpeg
    video/mp4
    image/png
```

In the example above, one of the alternative views is a `multipart/related` container which contains an HTML version of the message body that references the sibling video and images.

Now that you have a rough idea of how a message is structured and how to interpret various MIME entities, we can start figuring out how to actually render the message as intended.

**Using a MimeVisitor (the most accurate way of rendering a message)**

MimeKit includes a `MimeVisitor` class for visiting each node in the MIME tree structure. For example, the following `MimeVisitor` subclass could be used to generate HTML to be rendered by a browser control (such as `WebBrowser`):

```
/// <summary>
/// Visits a MimeMessage and generates HTML suitable to be rendered by a browser control.
/// </summary>
class HtmlPreviewVisitor : MimeVisitor
{
    List<MultipartRelated> stack = new List<MultipartRelated> ();
    List<MimeEntity> attachments = new List<MimeEntity> ();
    readonly string tempDir;
    string body;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new HtmlPreviewVisitor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tempDirectory">A temporary directory used for storing image files.</param>
    public HtmlPreviewVisitor (string tempDirectory)
    {
        tempDir = tempDirectory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of attachments that were in the MimeMessage.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<MimeEntity> Attachments {
        get { return attachments; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The HTML string that can be set on the BrowserControl.
    /// </summary>
    public string HtmlBody {
        get { return body ?? string.Empty; }
    }

    protected override void VisitMultipartAlternative (MultipartAlternative alternative)
    {
        // walk the multipart/alternative children backwards from greatest level of faithfulness to the least faithful
        for (int i = alternative.Count - 1; i >= 0 && body == null; i--)
            alternative[i].Accept (this);
    }

    protected override void VisitMultipartRelated (MultipartRelated related)
    {
        var root = related.Root;

        // push this multipart/related onto our stack
        stack.Add (related);

        // visit the root document
        root.Accept (this);

        // pop this multipart/related off our stack
        stack.RemoveAt (stack.Count - 1);
    }

    // look up the image based on the img src url within our multipart/related stack
    bool TryGetImage (string url, out MimePart image)
    {
        UriKind kind;
        int index;
        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Absolute))
            kind = UriKind.Absolute;
        else if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Relative))
            kind = UriKind.Relative;
        else
            kind = UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute;

        try {
            uri = new Uri (url, kind);
        } catch {
            image = null;
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = stack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ((index = stack[i].IndexOf (uri)) == -1)
                continue;

            image = stack[i][index] as MimePart;
            return image != null;
        }

        image = null;

        return false;
    }

    // Save the image to our temp directory and return a "file://" url suitable for
    // the browser control to load.
    // Note: if you'd rather embed the image data into the HTML, you can construct a
    // "data:" url instead.
    string SaveImage (MimePart image, string url)
    {
        string fileName = url.Replace (':', '_').Replace ('\\', '_').Replace ('/', '_');

        string path = Path.Combine (tempDir, fileName);

        if (!File.Exists (path)) {
            using (var output = File.Create (path))
                image.ContentObject.DecodeTo (output);
        }

        return "file://" + path.Replace ('\\', '/');
    }

    // Replaces <img src=...> urls that refer to images embedded within the message with
    // "file://" urls that the browser control will actually be able to load.
    void HtmlTagCallback (HtmlTagContext ctx, HtmlWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.Image && !ctx.IsEndTag && stack.Count > 0) {
            ctx.WriteTag (htmlWriter, false);

            // replace the src attribute with a file:// URL
            foreach (var attribute in ctx.Attributes) {
                if (attribute.Id == HtmlAttributeId.Src) {
                    MimePart image;
                    string url;

                    if (!TryGetImage (attribute.Value, out image)) {
                        htmlWriter.WriteAttribute (attribute);
                        continue;
                    }

                    url = SaveImage (image, attribute.Value);

                    htmlWriter.WriteAttributeName (attribute.Name);
                    htmlWriter.WriteAttributeValue (url);
                } else {
                    htmlWriter.WriteAttribute (attribute);
                }
            }
        } else if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.Body && !ctx.IsEndTag) {
            ctx.WriteTag (htmlWriter, false);

            // add and/or replace oncontextmenu="return false;"
            foreach (var attribute in ctx.Attributes) {
                if (attribute.Name.ToLowerInvariant () == "oncontextmenu")
                    continue;

                htmlWriter.WriteAttribute (attribute);
            }

            htmlWriter.WriteAttribute ("oncontextmenu", "return false;");
        } else {
            // pass the tag through to the output
            ctx.WriteTag (htmlWriter, true);
        }
    }

    protected override void VisitTextPart (TextPart entity)
    {
        TextConverter converter;

        if (body != null) {
            // since we've already found the body, treat this as an attachment
            attachments.Add (entity);
            return;
        }

        if (entity.IsHtml) {
            converter = new HtmlToHtml {
                HtmlTagCallback = HtmlTagCallback
            };
        } else if (entity.IsFlowed) {
            var flowed = new FlowedToHtml ();
            string delsp;

            if (entity.ContentType.Parameters.TryGetValue ("delsp", out delsp))
                flowed.DeleteSpace = delsp.ToLowerInvariant () == "yes";

            converter = flowed;
        } else {
            converter = new TextToHtml ();
        }

        body = converter.Convert (entity.Text);
    }

    protected override void VisitTnefPart (TnefPart entity)
    {
        // extract any attachments in the MS-TNEF part
        attachments.AddRange (entity.ExtractAttachments ());
    }

    protected override void VisitMessagePart (MessagePart entity)
    {
        // treat message/rfc822 parts as attachments
        attachments.Add (entity);
    }

    protected override void VisitMimePart (MimePart entity)
    {
        // realistically, if we've gotten this far, then we can treat this as an attachment
        // even if the IsAttachment property is false.
        attachments.Add (entity);
    }
}
```

And the way you'd use this visitor might look something like this:

```
void Render (MimeMessage message)
{
    var tmpDir = Path.Combine (Path.GetTempPath (), message.MessageId);
    var visitor = new HtmlPreviewVisitor (tmpDir);

    Directory.CreateDirectory (tmpDir);

    message.Accept (visitor);

    DisplayHtml (visitor.HtmlBody);
    DisplayAttachments (visitor.Attachments);
}
```

**Using the `TextBody` and `HtmlBody` Properties (the easiest way)**

To simplify the common task of getting the text of a message, `MimeMessage` includes two properties that can help you get the `text/plain` or `text/html` version of the message body. These are `TextBody` and `HtmlBody`, respectively.

Keep in mind, however, that at least with the `HtmlBody` property, it may be that the HTML part is a child of a `multipart/related`, allowing it to refer to images and other types of media that are also contained within that `multipart/related` entity. This property is really only a convenience property and is not a really good substitute for traversing the MIME structure yourself so that you may properly interpret related content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I didn't care about formatting and only wanted to save the raw text to a string, how would I do this, considering some of the messages I'm working with don't contain the text/plain part. Would I just have to remove the tags from the text/html or convert it in some way?

Comment: I would first check the `TextBody` property on the `MimeMessage`, but if the message doesn't contain a `text/plain` part, it will be null. Given that, yes, the next step would be to strip HTML tags. MimeKit has an `HtmlTokenizer` that you may find useful for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get it to work using the HtmlTokenizer.

Comment: This may be helpful as a starting point: https://gist.github.com/jstedfast/5c2189db1397aa776b3e

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works really well for removing HTML tags, although is there any easy way to extend this code to remove CSS as well? I'm left with code like [link](http://puu.sh/mJEtP/6c1cd006cf.png) still. If not, you've already helped me enough and I'll probably figure it out.

Comment: You can just add `HtmlTagId.Link` to the switch statement on line 203.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but relevant, can use inbuilt MimeKit to get body as text:

```
string body = mimeMessage.GetTextBody(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Plain);
```